# Laravel trying to get property of non-object works locally not on production

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem in production environment but works locally. When user is vendedor it works both locally and production, when it is not vendedor it works locally but not on production. dumping the variables whows different things in the attributes, original and guarded.

My controller is this.

```
if(auth::user()->vendedor == 1){

            $actividades = Actividad::with('Prospecto')->whereHas('Prospecto', function($q){
                $q->where('userid', auth::user()->id);
            })->get();

            dd($actividades);

        }else{
            $actividades = Actividad::all();
            dd($actividades);
        }
```

Local dump:

```
#items: array:137 [▼
    0 => Actividad {#578 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "actividads"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [ …10]
      #original: array:10 [ …10]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [ …1]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [ …1]
    }
```

Production dump:

```
#items: array:1 [▼
    0 => Actividad {#395 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "actividads"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:10 [▶]
      #original: array:10 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▶]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
```

As you can see, the arrays display differently in attributes, original and guarded.

I´ve made some tests and it works if i use differnt notation but I dont understand why is there a difference between local and production outputs.

```
prospect['empresa'];
```

instead of

```
prospect->empresa;
```

Im using Xampp locally and DO for production.

Comment: The problem might be `auth::user()`. Windows doesn't care about capitalization but Unix does. `auth::user()` is incorrect. It should be either `auth()->user()` or `Auth::user()`.

Comment: Might be a cache issue. Try `php artisan config:cache` & `php artisan cache:clear` on production server.